Are the Siegel upper half-spaces complex/Kähler submanifolds of one another?
Let us write $G_r=\mathrm{Sp}(2r,\mathbb{R})$ and $K_r=G_r\cap\mathrm{U}(2r)$. Then the Siegel upper half-space of rank $r$ is given (as a smooth manifold) by $X_r=G_r/K_r$. In this post it is shown that the block embedding
\begin{equation*}
G_r\hookrightarrow G_{r+1},\ A\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&&\\ &A&\\ &&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
induces a smooth embedding $X_r\hookrightarrow X_{r+1}$.
Question: Is the complex/Kähler structure on $X_r$ the restriction of the one on $X_{r+1}$?
More concretely, let us choose a $G_{r+1}$-invariant Riemannian metric $g_{r+1}$ on $X_{r+1}$ and let $g_r$ denote the restriction of $g_{r+1}$ to $X_r$. Can we find a $G_{r+1}$-invariant complex structure $J_{r+1}$ on $X_{r+1}$ that restricts to a complex structure on $X_r$, i.e. such that the Kähler form on $X_r$ is the restriction of the Kähler form on $X_{r+1}$?
What I tried so far: I am using the book Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces by Helgason, which describes how one can construct an (almost) complex structure on a Hermitian symmetric space $X=G/K$. Explicitly, if $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$ denotes the Cartan decomposition of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, one needs to find an element $z$ of order $4$ in the center of $K$, identify the tangent space $T_oX$ of $X$ at $o=eK$ with $\mathfrak{p}$, and extend the map $\mathrm{Ad}_G(z):\mathfrak{p}\to\mathfrak{p}$ in a $G$-invariant way to an (almost) complex structure on $X$. Helgason has the Siegel upper half-space as Exercise VIII.C but I think there is an error somewhere. He seems to choose $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}I&I\\ -I&I\end{pmatrix}$, but this has order $8$. Also $z^2$ seems to induce a trivial adjoint action on $\mathfrak{p}$, so I do not know how to fix this. Another problem is that I do not know how to properly embed $\mathfrak{p}_r$ into $\mathfrak{p}_{r+1}$.
Any help would be appreciated!

I think it is. It should be easier to work with the following model of the Siegel upper half-space: $$X_r=\{M\in\textrm{Sym}_r(\mathbb{C})\mid\textrm{Im}(M)\ \textrm{is positive definite}\}.$$ I will use the following anti-symmetric matrix to define $\textrm{Sp}(2r,\mathbb{R})$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&I_r\\
-I_r&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then, up to conjugation, the embedding you are refering to is $\textrm{Sp}(2r,\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow\textrm{Sp}(2r+2,\mathbb{R})$ given by $$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\
C&D\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}A&0&B&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
C&0&D&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ where $1$ denotes the 1-by-1 block with single entry $1$. The corresponding embedding should be $$X_r\to X_{r+1},\ M\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\
0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Since $X_r$ is an open subset a complex vector space, namely $\textrm{Sym}_r(\mathbb{C})$, it admits a natural complex structure which makes it a Hermitian symmetric space. From this point of view, one clearly sees that the complex structure on $X_r$ is the restriction of the one on $X_{r+1}$.
